# Two Dynamic Forms via Select Option (datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, datepicker

I would like to choose between form_two and for_three in the main_form(fiddle at the bottom of the post). Under the main form should be one of the two forms(form_two/form_three). I can choose between the two forms, but they are not editable, because they are not in the source code, if I inspect the code with the browser.

I would like to have a datepicker from jquery in it, to submit the date. But I have got the problem, that I can see the two(form_two/form_three) different forms in the browser, but if I look in the source code, there is no form in the dom.

Here is my code:

Form to select one of these forms (main_form)

```
    <!-- Content begin -->
<div id="content">
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return false">
        <fieldset name="inseration_option">
            <legend>Inseratauswahl</legend>
            <label for="choice">Auswahl:</label>
            <select name="choice" id="choice" size="1">
                <option value="joboffers" selected="selected">Jobangebot aufgeben</option>
                <option value="workeroffers">Job finden</option>
            </select>
            <button value="ok" id="choice_btn" name="choice_btn" >Los</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="form"></div>
<!-- Content end -->
```

form_two

```
<!-- Content begin -->
<div id="content">
    <form action="index.php?site=suche_inserat" method="post">
        <fieldset name="search_option">
            <legend>Suche Inserate</legend>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Jobinformationen</legend>
                <label for="j_select">Jobart:</label><br>
                <select name="j_select" size="1">
                    <option>Gelegenheitsjob</option>
                    <option>Ausbildungsplatz</option>
                    <option>Praktika</option>
                    <option>Fachkräfte</option>
                </select><br>
                <label for="j_cat">Berufsfeld:</label><br>
                <select name="j_cat" size="1">
                    <option>Bau, Architektur, Vermessung</option>
                    <option>Dienstleistung</option>
                    <option>Elektro</option>
                    <option>Gesellschaft-, Geisteswissenschaften</option>
                    <option>Gesundheit</option>
                    <option>IT, Computer</option>
                    <option>Kunst, Kultur, Gestaltung</option>
                    <option>Landwirtschaft, Natur, Umwelt</option>
                    <option>Medien</option>
                    <option>Metall, Maschinenbau</option>
                    <option>Naturwissenschaften</option>
                    <option>Produktion, Fertigung</option>
                    <option>Soziales, Pädagogik</option>
                    <option>Technik, Technologiefelder</option>
                    <option>Verkehr, Logistik</option>
                    <option>Wirtschaft, Verwaltung</option>
                </select><br>
                <label for="j_destrict">Stadtteil:</label><br>
                <select name="j_destrict" size="1">
                    <option>Charlottenburg</option>
                    <option>Friedrichshain</option>
                    <option>Hellersdorf</option>
                    <option>Köpenick</option>
                    <option>Kreuzberg</option>
                    <option>Lichtenberg</option>
                    <option>Marzahn</option>
                    <option>Mitte</option>
                    <option>Neuköln</option>
                    <option>Pankow</option>
                    <option>Reinickendorf</option>
                    <option>Schöneberg</option>
                    <option>Spandau</option>
                    <option>Steglitz</option>
                    <option>Tempelhof</option>
                    <option>Treptow</option>
                    <option>Zehlendorf</option>
                </select><br>
                <label for="j_date">Gesucht ab Datum:</label><br>
                <input type="date" name="j_date"><br>
                <label for="j_cash">Vergütung:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="j_cash"><br>
                <label for="j_title">Titel:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="j_title"><br>
                <label for="j_desc">Beschreibung:</label><br>
                <textarea name="j_desc"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Auftraggeberinformationen</legend>
                <label for="j_company">Unternehmen/Firma:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="j_company"><br>
                <label for="j_street">Straße/Nr.:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="j_street"><br>
                <label for="j_plz">PLZ:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="j_plz"><br>
                <label for="j_town">Ort:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="j_town"><br>
                <label for="j_pic">Foto/Logo:</label><br>
                <input type="file" name="j_pic">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Kontaktinformationen</legend>
                <label for="j_email">E-Mail-Adresse:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="j_email"><br>
                <label for="j_phone">Telefonnummer:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="j_phone"><br>
                <label for="j_fax">Fax:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="j_fax">
            </fieldset>
        <button name="search_btn">Inserieren</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Content end -->
```

form_three

```
<!-- Content begin -->
<div id="content">
    <form action="index.php?site=finde_inserat" method="post">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset name="find_option">
            <legend>Finde Inserat</legend>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Jobinformationen</legend>
                <label for="w_select">Jobart:</label><br>
                <select name="w_select" size="1">
                    <option>Gelegenheitsjob</option >
                    <option>Ausbildungsplatz</option>
                    <option>Praktika</option>
                    <option>Fachkräfte</option>
                </select><br>
                <label for="w_cat">Berufsfeld:</label><br>
                <select name="w_cat" size="1">
                    <option>Bau, Architektur, Vermessung</option>
                    <option>Dienstleistung</option>
                    <option>Elektro</option>
                    <option>Gesellschaft-, Geisteswissenschaften</option>
                    <option>Gesundheit</option>
                    <option>IT, Computer</option>
                    <option>Kunst, Kultur, Gestaltung</option>
                    <option>Landwirtschaft, Natur, Umwelt</option>
                    <option>Medien</option>
                    <option>Metall, Maschinenbau</option>
                    <option>Naturwissenschaften</option>
                    <option>Produktion, Fertigung</option>
                    <option>Soziales, Pädagogik</option>
                    <option>Technik, Technologiefelder</option>
                    <option>Verkehr, Logistik</option>
                    <option>Wirtschaft, Verwaltung</option>
                </select><br>
                <label for="w_destrict">Stadtteil:</label><br>
                <select name="w_destrict" size="1">
                    <option>Charlottenburg</option>
                    <option>Friedrichshain</option>
                    <option>Hellersdorf</option>
                    <option>Köpenick</option>
                    <option>Kreuzberg</option>
                    <option>Lichtenberg</option>
                    <option>Marzahn</option>
                    <option>Mitte</option>
                    <option>Neuköln</option>
                    <option>Pankow</option>
                    <option>Reinickendorf</option>
                    <option>Schöneberg</option>
                    <option>Spandau</option>
                    <option>Steglitz</option>
                    <option>Tempelhof</option>
                    <option>Treptow</option>
                    <option>Zehlendorf</option>
                </select><br>
                <label for="w_date">Verfügbar ab Datum:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="w_date" id="w_date"><br>
                <label for="w_cash">Vergütung:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="w_cash"><br>
                <label for="w_title">Titel:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="w_title"><br>
                <label for="w_desc">Beschreibung:</label><br>
                <textarea name="w_desc"></textarea><br>
                <label for="w_pic">Profilbild/Foto:</label><br>
                <input type="file" name="w_pic">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Kontaktinformationen</legend>
                <label for="w_email">E-Mail-Adresse:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="w_email"><br>
                <label for="w_phone">Telefonnummer:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="w_phone"><br>
                <label for="w_fax">Fax:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="w_fax">
            </fieldset>
        <button name="find_btn">Inserieren</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the JS File

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var pfad = "";

$("#choice_btn").click(function(){
 //console.log($("#choice").val());
if ( $("#choice").val() == "joboffers" ){

    pfad = "sites/suche_inserat.php";

    }else{

    pfad = "sites/finde_inserat.php";
 //console.log($("#choice").val());
    }

    $( "#form" ).load( pfad );
    $( "#w_date" ).datepicker();
  /*
    $.ajax({
        url:        pfad,
        type:       "POST",
        async:      true,
        success:    function(callback) {
                    //console.log(callback);
            $("#form").innerHTML(callback);
        }  
        })
   */       

    })
});
```

Sorry for my english!! I hope somebody can help me!

edit: Here is a fiddle: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/bus74ezp/)

(I do not know, how to make more html windows in fiddle) :(

Comment: I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqdsfq6y/7/) based on your code, but it's unclear to me what you are asking.  Right now, the jQuery-UI datepicker is not instantiated until the `#choice_btn` button is clicked.  Do you mean for the datepicker to instantiate on document.ready?  Are you including the stylesheet for jQuery-UI?  Also, I only see one form.  Can you make a JSFiddle that might help illustrate what the desired behavior of your code is, versus the problems that you are experiencing?

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/bus74ezp/)) as well, but I do not know, how to make more than one html windows. I have got three php files. One for the form selection and the two others for the forms. I hope, you know what I mean.

With my example I can choose between the two forms, but the datepicker is not working. Because I am not getting the two forms in the dom.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding your explanation of your code.  For instance, when you say "I have got a form with "two select options" and when I hit one of these options and submit, it will show a different form.", which *specific* forms are you talking about?  I think you might get a better response if you edited your question to make it more clear and specific with respect to *which* forms are doing *what*.

Comment: I have updated it. There are three forms in the html(main_form, form_two and form_three) in fiddle. In my original code these three forms are three different files.

In the main_form I want to choose between form_two and form_three and there should be loaded under the main_form. 

They are showing up, but there are not in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I made it this way([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqdsfq6y/19/)) now. Maby could someone have a look at it.
I have took all forms in one file. So I do not need three diffrent files and have to load them into it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#form_1").hide();
$("#form_2").hide();

$("#choice_btn").click(function(){

if ( $("#choice").val() == "joboffers" ){
    $("#form_2").hide();
    $("#form_1").show();
}else{
    $("#form_1").hide();
    $("#form_2").show();
}
})

$("#j_date").datepicker();
$("#w_date").datepicker();

});
```